# Is it possible to use jQuery and Django on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm trying to just a jQuery function to show a table on a Django page. When I test the script on jsfiddle, it works great but it's not working on my Django site. Do I need to import something into Django to make it work?

This is what I have thus far:

html file:

```
<table class="panel">
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3 class="tblheader"><h1>Statistics</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="spoiler">Click for Spoilers</button>
```

javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.spoiler').click(function() {
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the html file? How are you including jquery and your own js file? How are you serving those files?

Comment: jQuery and JS files are included in the base.html file using {% load staticfiles %} and script links to the files themselves, just like you would do with bootstrap and css files. I only included the table since that's the only area where that is affected by JS.

Comment: OK but is Django actually serving those staticfiles? Are they being loaded in your browser? Can you see them in the browser dev tools?

Comment: All of my CSS is loading properly for sure. I call JS using `<script href="{% static 'js/webapp.js' %}"></script>` and it shows in the header on inspection. However, it does not show up in the network panel (everything else including jQuery is there). Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: Scripts are linked by `src`, not `href`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go jump off a bridge now. lol

Answer (score -1):

You should add reference to jquery script from your Django html template, for example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

More information on [jquery site](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: I have that in my base.html file along with my specific webapp.js file, so that's not the issue.

Comment: in your previous comment it seems that you have used <script href= instead of <script src=